# Add specific condition with params in yii1

Tags: php, postgresql, yii

I use postgres extension - ip4r, and i want create condition, something like this:

```
$criteria = new \CDbCriteria();
$criteria->params = [
        ':address'     => $ip
    ];
$criteria->addCondition("iprange(ip_from, ip_to) >>= (':address')::ip4");
```

but it doesn't work, why?

I know postgresql query work true, mistake in params

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suddenly someone will need a solution, the mistake was in quotes

```
$criteria = new \CDbCriteria(); 
$criteria->params = [
    ':address'     => $ip
];
$criteria->addCondition("iprange(ip_from, ip_to) >>= (:address)::ip4");
```